# Как найти точку на окружности?

Tags: c#, геометрия, координаты

У меня есть точка А внутри окружности. Мне нужно найти находящуюся на окружности **вертикально под А** вторую точку Б, получить ее координаты X, Y. Как это сделать?

Известно:

- радиус
- координаты X и Y центра окружности
- координаты X и Y точки А.

Найти:

- координаты X и Y точки Б.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это вопрос скорее про геометрию чем про программирование. Соответственно когда ты научишся выводить координаты на листке бумаги - уже потом пробуй программировать. А если что не выходит - подойди к преподавателю геометрии)

Comment: Формула окружности известна. Решаем её относительно координаты у и получаем квадратное уравнение. Остальное дело техники.

Comment: составить уравнение окружности по координате центра и радиусу, взять координату x точки A и вычислить по уравнению окружности координаты y точек на окружности, потом выбрать или нижнюю или ближайшую из точек, в зависимости от того, какая именно из точек нужна.

Comment: @Эникейщик что за формула окружности? Гугл по запросу выдает формулы площади круга и длины окружности, что не относится к моему вопросу.

Comment: Самая обычная. Плохо гуглишь.

Comment: @Эникейщик x2+y2 - это формула окружности?

Comment: @Lesnikus строго говоря, то, что вы написали это вообще не формула. Но да, речь об этом.

Comment: @Эникейщик как x2+y2 решить относительно координаты Y, как вы указали? Совсем не очевидно.

Comment: Потому что х2+у2 это не уравнение! В уравнении присутствует знак =

Comment: @Эникейщик чувствую себя двоечником в школе. Я просто думал, что формула и уравнение- разные вещи. Т.е. нам надо x2+y2="что-то там" превратить в y2="что-то там" - x2 ?

Comment: Да. "Что-то там" это радиус :) потом получится квадратное уравнение. Меньший корень будет координата у под точкой А, больший - над точкой. Если корень один, то точка А сама лежит на окружности.

Comment: http://math.hashcode.ru/ ВОТ ТУТУ ответ могут дать

Answer (score 2):

Задача очень простая. Первым делом проведем отрезки из центра окружности в точки А и Б, а также соединим отрезком точки А и Б, получим прямоугольный треугольник. Затем найдем длину отрезка ОА по формуле d^2= (х2— х1)^2+ (y2— y1)^2, где (х1,у1)А и (х2,у2)Б. После чего находим длину отрезка АБ по теореме Пифагора АБ^2=ОБ^2-ОА^2. Подставляем значение длины отрезка и координаты точки А в туже формулу d^2= (х2— х1)^2+ (y2— y1)^2, в эту же формулу подставляем значение длины отрезка ОА и координаты центра окружности, получаем систему 2 квадратных уравнений, выражаем одно через другое подставляем и решаем в итоге получаем координаты точки Б.

Comment: Система из двух квадратных? Это сложно, здесь достаточно одного уравнения.

Comment: Как нам провести отрезок в точку Б, если мы не знаем ее координат?

Comment: Вам чтобы 2 точки соединить не нужно знать их координат, тем более вы в точку Б проводите радиус из точки О(т.к. точка Б лежит на окружности) и высоту из точки А(т.к. Б вертикально под ней)  и получаете прямоугольный треугольник